# How fast can a stepper motor run?

Tags: stepper-motor

How to determine the maximum RPM that a stepper motor can run at?
(2.6V, 1.2A stepper for example)

Comment: You carefully read the documentation to see if it tells you what you need to know, and if it doesn't, find a motor with the type of documentation you need.

Comment: @ScottSeidman motor documentation by itself will not answer this, as it depends as much on the driver as the motor.  The motor inductance will be a key input, though the given voltage vs. current suggest it is moderately low.

Comment: What is your torque? You have to know your load if you want to know how fast it can run. If the torque is too high it wont even turn. Also have you done a simple google search on the matter? https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+max+rpm+stepper+can+run+at&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accelerate as long as you can add power to the system.

To add power, you need to create a magnetic field that leads the rotor, which means you need to apply enough power to set up the field in time before the rotor reaches it, and have it collapse in time so you don't brake. The faster the rotor goes, the more the coils' inductivity works against you there.

You can increase the voltage with increasing speed, as shorter, higher pulses will not reach the current limit of the motor because of the inductivity, but there are limits when either the added power equals the power lost through friction or the load, or the voltage exceeds the isolation inside the motor.

In either case, you need to ramp up the speed in a controlled way, and look at the back EMF to determine whether you can still increase speed.

Comment: Yes, though in a practical system one also needs to consider deviations from the simple model, like margin for inconsistent loads, and the possibility of some step rates exciting mechanical system resonances.

Comment: I agree the limiting factor on speed is friction/torque avail vs eddy current and skin effect losses at high speed. The trick is to control the slew rate and ramp without clogging or skipping a step due to torque vs rotational inertia of load. but if losses are zero for friction, driver LC parameters often limit the speed with electrical resonance and mechanical resonance.  Test one with NO load and monitor V,I loop with low L probe (very short gnd lead or none) and use very low RdsOn driver compared to Coil DCR(<2%), then adjust down acceleration ramp with increasing mechanical load

Comment: To reduce  EMI from fast current dI/dt current pulses, use ferrite sleeve with many turns of motor wires thru large mu toroid. This raises CM impedance but keeps Differential impedance low. e.g. 100-150 Ohms to reduce pulse ringing. Impedance tradeoffs may be required to match source , cable and load Z for fast commutation rates at high speed and tune deadtime for optimal time over temperature and load range.

Comment: The tradeoffs with microstepping is torque and speed but quieter operation.  Mechanical resonances and runout must be identified in the motor bearings and the load. I have seen DIY PCB milling machines that work better with large spindles in series with small stepper motors to mill copper on PCB's just because the large spindle had tighter bearings for low radial runout but driven by a small stepper motor since there was almost no  load driving a milling bit into copper board.